# Create an html mailto link from a database fetch

Tags: php, html, database, fetch, mailto

I'm having difficulty creating a mailto link from a user's inputted email address that's stored in a database (this is used for a comments section). I was hoping to create a new line with the email address printed with a mailto hyperlink. Instead, it doesn't print the email address, but instead turns all text below that line into a mailto hyperlink. See attached pictures for clarification.

```
echo "<h3><u>Latest Comments:</u></h3>";
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<hr />";
echo "<p>".$fetch['comment']."<p>";     
echo "<header><h3>By: ".$fetch['comment_by']."</h3><br>"; 
echo "<a href='mailto:".$fetch['email'].">".$fetch['email']."</a></br>";
$sqldate = $fetch['datetime'];
$date=strtotime($sqldate);
echo "<span class='date'>On: " .date("m/d/Y, g:i A", $date)."</span></header></p>";
```

Notice, it fetches the correct email address, but doesn't create the hyperlink correctly using html. Also note this is all contained inside php tags.

[link to photo showing problem](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2DCA8656DB14D615!32328&authkey=!AFiImfhoESWfjCM&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cjpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a quote:

```
echo "<a href='mailto:".$fetch['email']."'>".$fetch['email']."</a></br>";
                                    -----^
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the quick response - of course I would have missed a simple quote...I'm still very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it is not acceptable to have this mess between PHP and HTML what usually ends with "missing a quote".

Your View should be something like

```
<h3><u>Latest Comments:</u></h3>

<?php foreach($records as $record) : ?>
<hr />
<p><?php echo $record['comment'] ?></p>
<header>
    <h3>By: <?php echo $record['comment_by'] ?></h3>
    <a href="mailto:<?php echo $record['email'] ?>"><?php echo $record['email'] ?></a><br />
    <span class="date">On: <?php echo date("m/d/Y, g:i A", strtotime($record['datetime'])) ?></span>
</header>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Help yourself and read [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)